# symfony2 mediabundle field type

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, media, image-uploading

i'm using this media bundle
http://symfony.com/doc/master/cmf/bundles/media/introduction.html

the problem i have is that i dont know to which field type to set the entity field

```
/**
 * @var Image
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="image", type="???WHAT TYPE GOES HERE???", length=255)
 */
private $image;
```

i've tryed string(works on creation but cant edit or show)

gives me this error

```
The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class 
Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\MediaBundle\Doctrine\Phpcr\Image, but is a(n) string. 
You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to null 
or by adding a view transformer that transforms 
a(n) string to an instance of Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\MediaBundle\Doctrine\Phpcr\Image.
```

also tryed to put Image and Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\MediaBundle\Doctrine\Phpcr\Image
 does not recognize this types.
and finally tryed data_class=null which is not recognized as one of the options for this field